# C++ - str(n)cmp(i) () for C++ style strings

Tags: c++, string

What are the equivalents of the functions `strcmpi()`, `strncmp()` and `strncmpi()` for C++ style strings?

Please do not suggest using things like `strcmpi(str1.c_str, str2.c_str)` etc.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Look at std::string.compare

Comment: Relevant: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/029.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Boost you could use this to do case-insensitive comparation:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

std::string str1 = "hello, world!";
std::string str2 = "hELLO, World!";

if (boost::iequals(str1, str2))
{
    // Strings are identical
}
```